# Existence of continuous functions defined on $x\geq 0$ such that $f(4x)-f(2x)-f(x)=0$

Tags: continuity

> How to show that there exists a non-zero continuous function defined on $x\geq 0$ such that $f(4x)-f(2x)-f(x)=0$?

By setting $a_n=f(2^nx)$, then $f(x)=(-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n f(x/2^n)$. Then what happens next?

Answer (score 1):

There is $f(x) = \phi^{\log_2(x)}$, with $f(0) = 0$, where $\phi = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})}{2}$, the golden ratio.

So we have:
$$f(4x)-f(2x)-f(x) = \phi^{\log_2(x)} (\phi^2 - \phi - 1) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $\,f(x):=\phi^y\,g(z)\,$ where
$$ \phi:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2,\quad y:=\log_2(x)
 \quad\text{ and } \quad z:=x/2^{\lfloor y\rfloor}. \tag{1} $$
Now
$$ f(2x)=\phi^{y+1}g(z),\quad f(4x)=\phi^{y+2}g(z),\quad\text{ and }
\tag{2}$$
$$ f(4x)-f(2x)-f(x) = \phi^y(y^2-y-1)g(z) = 0. \tag{3} $$
If the function
$\,g(z)\,$ is continuous on $\,[1,2]\,$ and $\,g(2)=\phi\, g(1)\,$
then $\,f(x)\,$ is continuous for all $\,x>0.$